# ASPNetCore wepApi Authentication based on simple condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

So I am new to Rest and implemented my first webapi from scratch. I now want to build in authentcation (http) based on certain conditions. Everywhere I read on username and password. Tokens ect ect. Is there a authentication term for just normal checks. Basically the user needs to send in 2 things. A appId and correlationId. The appId needs to match an item out of a list of allowed apps(will probably be in a configuration file) and I need to see if the correlationId are filled. If these 2 conditions are met, user/app can proceed calling the rest of the services in the api. I am not asking code, as I will implement it myself. a link or term I can search for on the web that will meet my requirements will be great.

Comment: I think this link useful: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you want is to use a middleware. For example here is a custom auhtorization based on headers:

```
      public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IConfiguration configuration)
                {

                            var isAuthorized = Authorize();

                            if (isAuthorized)
                            {
                               ..do your stuff
                               await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                await UnauthorizedResponseAsync(httpContext);
                            }

                }

          private static async Task UnauthorizedResponseAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
            {
                httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized");
                return;
            }
```